# What can be the reason for getting this log output - Lost connection to device - when executing flutter run?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

- Why is the device getting disconnected with the log stating - Lost connection to device - after
  excuting flutter run?
- Everything works fine till the login
  screen, where the user is able to correctly login using google Sign
  in, but the next 'HOME' screen, as it starts loading, breaks & I
  receive the following log, as a preceding to the 
  lost connection to device - statement.

```
Build fingerprint: 'HONOR/BND-AL10/HWBND-H:9/HONORBND-AL10/9.1.0.154C675:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Happend: 'Sun Dec  1 09:45:39 2019
'
SYSVMTYPE: Art
APPVMTYPE: Art
pid: 29781, tid: 29842, name: 1.ui  >>> com.obodo.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000001  x1  00000076b7ddde60  x2  00000076b7c00000  x3  0000000000000002
    x4  00000000000001dd  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000076b410cef0  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  00000076ca3848a0  x9  00000076ca3848a0  x10 00000000000001dd  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000000000000004  x13 0000000000000202  x14 0000000000000002  x15 00000076b410cef0
    x16 0000007754b32bd8  x17 0000007754ac6d48  x18 0000000000000001  x19 00000076a31fe820
    x20 00000076cda472a0  x21 00000076ac192bb0  x22 00000076ac192ca0  x23 0000000000000045
    x24 00000076ca275058  x25 00000076b410d248  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000001
    x28 0000000000000045  x29 00000076b410d3a0
    sp  00000076b410d0f0  lr  00000076b52e5c58  pc  00000076b52e1990
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000011d3990  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #01 pc 00000000011d7c54  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #02 pc 00000000011cf744  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #03 pc 00000000011d5a78  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #04 pc 00000000011d6154  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #05 pc 00000000011d55b0  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #06 pc 00000000011da7c8  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #07 pc 00000000000142cc  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+932)
    #08 pc 0000000000013e8c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
    #09 pc 0000000000012278  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+96)
    #10 pc 00000000011da74c  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #11 pc 00000000011d54fc  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #12 pc 00000000011d86a0  /data/app/com.obodo.app-zqtWiY4hrLL6aB0_3pwPjA==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x11c0000)
    #13 pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #14 pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a very similar error and solved it as follows:

1. Remove the emulator app or your physical device
2. Close the emulator or restart the physical device
3. Execute the `flutter clean` command
4. Close the IDE (in my case Intellij)
5. Open the project again and run your app.

**NOTE:** The above worked for iOS where I got the error of `Lost connection to device`

Comment: I already tried this with my Windows + android setup, but didn't help.

Comment: As a side-note, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

- Okay, So I tried to figure it out, but in no vain.  Finally, after
  trying everything, I changed my flutter channel to from 'stable' to
  'dev', and it works great now.
- This link should help with the flutter tool syntax to [switch channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#switching-flutter-channels).

> I don't exactly know the reason behind why this is happening, but if
>   anyone does, do share here or point me towards the
>   source, I will be obliged.